# Tikz picture as large as possible on A4 Page

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, margins

I'm trying to make an origami template in tikz. I've made a latex document with 0.5cm margins on all 4 sides. Here is my tikz code:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[top=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm, left=0.5cm, right=0.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  % \draw (0,0) rectangle (28.7cm,20cm);

    \draw (14.45, 4.9) -- (14.6, 17.0);
    \draw (14.6, 17.0) -- (26.5, 16.8);
    \draw (26.5, 16.8) -- (26.4, 4.7);
    \draw (26.4, 4.7)  -- (20.43, 4.1);
    \draw (20.43, 4.1) -- (14.45, 4.9);

    \draw (20.43, 4.1) -- (14.6, 17.0);
    \draw (20.43, 4.1) -- (26.5, 16.8);

    \draw (14.6, 17)   -- (2.7, 17.2);
    \draw (2.7, 17.2)  -- (2.6, 5.1);
    \draw (2.6, 5.1)   -- (8.47, 4.3);
    \draw (8.47, 4.3)  -- (14.45, 4.9);

    \draw (8.47, 4.3)  -- (2.7, 17.2);
    \draw (8.47, 4.3)  -- (14.6, 17.0);

    \draw (2.6, 5.1)   -- (1.3, 5.4);
    \draw (1.3, 5.4)   -- (1.4, 14.5);
    \draw (1.4, 14.5)  -- (2.7, 17.2);

    \draw (8.47, 4.3)  -- (8.7, 0.4);
    \draw (8.7, 0.4)   -- (10.65, 0.6);
    \draw (10.65, 0.6) -- (10.55, 1.5);
    \draw (10.55, 1.5) -- (12.99, 1.7);
    \draw (12.99, 1.7) -- (13.05, 0.86);
    \draw (13.05, 0.86) -- (14.97, 1.1);
    \draw (14.97, 1.1) -- (14.45, 4.9);

    \draw (14.45, 4.9) -- (17.18, 2.59);
    \draw (17.18, 2.59) -- (15.99, 1.95);
    \draw (15.99, 1.95) -- (15.97, 1.48);
    \draw (15.97, 1.48) -- (20.08, 1.10);
    \draw (20.08, 1.10) -- (20.43, 4.1);

    \draw (20.43, 4.1) -- (22.56, 1.24);
    \draw (22.56, 1.24) -- (22.69, 0.11);
    \draw (22.69, 0.11) -- (25.04, 0.44);
    \draw (25.04, 0.44) -- (24.93, 1.48);
    \draw (24.93, 1.48) -- (26.4, 4.7);

    \draw (2.6, 5.1) -- (2.08, 2.06);
    \draw (2.08, 2.06) -- (6.1, 1.35);
    \draw (6.1, 1.35) -- (6.15, 1.82);
    \draw (6.15, 1.82) -- (5.31, 2.77);
    \draw (5.31, 2.77) -- (8.47, 4.3);

    \node (mid) at (14.6, 17.0);
    \node (rh) at (20.48, 18.5);
    \node (r) at (26.5, 16.8);
    \node (lh) at (8.38, 18.63);
    \node (l) at (2.7, 17.2);

    \path (mid) edge [out=80,in=145,bend angle=180,looseness=1.45] (rh);
    \path (r) edge [out=96,in=35,bend angle=180,looseness=1.4] (rh);

    \path (mid) edge [out=100,in=35,bend angle=180,looseness=1.35] (lh);
    \path (l) edge [out=86,in=145,bend angle=180,looseness=1.45] (lh);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following page:
[image]

If you look, the whole image seems to be shifted down. I have a commented out rectangle at the start of my tikz code that should put a border around the printable area.

If I comment out the last 4 lines (the curved lines), then the tikz picture is in the correct place.

I'm not too worried about precise scale, what I really want is for this to be as large as possible on the page - i.e. the top and bottom of the image should touch the margin of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a zero length for top and bottom.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0cm, bottom=0cm, left=0.5cm, right=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\noindent
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (28.7cm,20cm);
    \draw (14.45, 4.9) -- (14.6, 17.0);
    \draw (14.6, 17.0) -- (26.5, 16.8);
    \draw (26.5, 16.8) -- (26.4, 4.7);
    \draw (26.4, 4.7)  -- (20.43, 4.1);
    \draw (20.43, 4.1) -- (14.45, 4.9);

    \draw (20.43, 4.1) -- (14.6, 17.0);
    \draw (20.43, 4.1) -- (26.5, 16.8);

    \draw (14.6, 17)   -- (2.7, 17.2);
    \draw (2.7, 17.2)  -- (2.6, 5.1);
    \draw (2.6, 5.1)   -- (8.47, 4.3);
    \draw (8.47, 4.3)  -- (14.45, 4.9);

    \draw (8.47, 4.3)  -- (2.7, 17.2);
    \draw (8.47, 4.3)  -- (14.6, 17.0);

    \draw (2.6, 5.1)   -- (1.3, 5.4);
    \draw (1.3, 5.4)   -- (1.4, 14.5);
    \draw (1.4, 14.5)  -- (2.7, 17.2);

    \draw (8.47, 4.3)  -- (8.7, 0.4);
    \draw (8.7, 0.4)   -- (10.65, 0.6);
    \draw (10.65, 0.6) -- (10.55, 1.5);
    \draw (10.55, 1.5) -- (12.99, 1.7);
    \draw (12.99, 1.7) -- (13.05, 0.86);
    \draw (13.05, 0.86) -- (14.97, 1.1);
    \draw (14.97, 1.1) -- (14.45, 4.9);

    \draw (14.45, 4.9) -- (17.18, 2.59);
    \draw (17.18, 2.59) -- (15.99, 1.95);
    \draw (15.99, 1.95) -- (15.97, 1.48);
    \draw (15.97, 1.48) -- (20.08, 1.10);
    \draw (20.08, 1.10) -- (20.43, 4.1);

    \draw (20.43, 4.1) -- (22.56, 1.24);
    \draw (22.56, 1.24) -- (22.69, 0.11);
    \draw (22.69, 0.11) -- (25.04, 0.44);
    \draw (25.04, 0.44) -- (24.93, 1.48);
    \draw (24.93, 1.48) -- (26.4, 4.7);

    \draw (2.6, 5.1) -- (2.08, 2.06);
    \draw (2.08, 2.06) -- (6.1, 1.35);
    \draw (6.1, 1.35) -- (6.15, 1.82);
    \draw (6.15, 1.82) -- (5.31, 2.77);
    \draw (5.31, 2.77) -- (8.47, 4.3);

    \node (mid) at (14.6, 17.0){};
    \node (rh) at (20.48, 18.5){};
    \node (r) at (26.5, 16.8){};
    \node (lh) at (8.38, 18.63){};
    \node (l) at (2.7, 17.2){};

    \path (mid) edge [out=80,in=145,bend angle=180,looseness=1.45] (rh);
    \path (r) edge [out=96,in=35,bend angle=180,looseness=1.4] (rh);

    \path (mid) edge [out=100,in=35,bend angle=180,looseness=1.35] (lh);
    \path (l) edge [out=86,in=145,bend angle=180,looseness=1.45] (lh);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

it looks like that tikz have some trailing spaces. However, here is the output of my code:

[image]

Comment: Actually I had to set it to -0.5 for it to work for me, but thanks! This solved my problem! (albeit in probably the hackiest way possible).